# Using JLists and ListModels

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have defined a `DirectoryListModel` class that extends the `AbstractListModel` class from the Java Api.

Internally, I have a list of `File` objects. I have defined the `getElementAt(int index)` method as:

```
@Override
public Object getElementAt(int index) {
    return directoryElements.get(index)
}
```

The problem is that when I try to run my JList with my `DirectoryListModel`, it is going to show up the full paths of files instead of just the filenames. I could change this code to:

```
@Override
public Object getElementAt(int index) {
    return directoryElements.get(index).getName();

}
```

and it'd work wonders, but the problem is that in the onclick event I'll want to have the File objects so I can do some checking with them (check if they're directories, etc).
If I make `getElementAt()` return a String, I'm losing that possibility, thus I'd like to konw if there is a way I can format my File objects before the JList shows them in my window or if is there any **simple** and **elegant** way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would extend the DefaultListCellRenderer to add your custom code for two reasons:

a) you will get the default behaviour of the default renderer, like Borders, row selection highlighting...
b) The renderer (like all Swing renderers) has been optimized for faster painting.

```
class MyRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer
{
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
        Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list,value,index,false,false) ;
        JLabel label = (JLabel)c;

        label.setText(...);

        return c ;
    }
}
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information on renderers.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing for you to do is to use renderers.  Renderers, as you can gather from the name, are used to play the `V` to the backing data's `M` in the `MVC` paradigm.  In this case, your `File` is the backing data, and the renderer is used to display just the part of the `File` that you want displayed.

Were you to implement a custom cell renderer, extending a `JLabel` and implementing `ListCellRenderer`, you could start with a simple attempt by implementing the one interface method like this:

```
 public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,
                                               Object value,
                                               int index,
                                               boolean isSelected,
                                               boolean cellHasFocus) {

     setText(((File)value).getName());
     return this;
 }
```

Take a look at the [`ListCellRenderer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) javadoc for some more guidance.